# check status of URL with ajax/json

Tags: ajax, json

I need to retrieve JSON data from a URL periodically, and update my page accordingly.

I have a table.  Each row has a link that I would link to test its status say, every 20 seconds.

This could be achieved using a page refresh meta tag, but I think ajax would be a much nicer solution.

Should I be using $.getJSON?   (im pretty new to ajax/json)

Comment: In the world of AJAX this is known as polling or [periodic refresh](http://ajaxpatterns.org/Periodic_Refresh).  Can't really write anything as an answer that hasn't been said a million times.  Also depends on which library (if any) you want to use - add that to your Google search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're basically there. First of all, `$.getJSON()` is just a convenience method to `$.ajax()` where the `datatype: 'json'`, and it's a best practice to always stick with `$.ajax()`. You want to call `setTimeout` within the function that you want to asynchronously load - so you'll be using recursion here. The benefit is that you can repeatedly make your AJAX call, but only when the previous method is completed, so everything operates correctly. A quick example of this would be something like the following:

```
$(function() {
    var myFunction = function() {
        $.ajax({ 
            url: '/place-for-cool-stuff', 
            datatype: 'json',
            data: { ... data you need to send, e.g. method arguments ... }
         }).done(function (data) {
             ... do stuff with the data you get back ...
         }).fail(function (jqXHR) {
             ... be smart and handle failures ...
         }).always(function () {
             ... no matter what happens do this stuff ...
             setTimeout(myFunction, 20000);
         });
     };
});
```

Comment: thanks acconrad.  I think  I can get the setTimeout side of things working no problem,. But the rest is still very cloudy! How for example, do I apply the function to each row in a table.  I want to apply a status of 'good', 'bad', 'building' to a <td> cell  (depending on the result of the JSON)

Comment: Check out [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) where you can pass in all of the TDs in a table and apply a function to each one. Also make sure to check the edit in my answer for a better way to keep calling your functions.